# VC6 project missing msvcp71d.dll?

Tags: dynamic-linking, visual-c++-6, msvcrt

I've been searching for a while now, and i came to understand that msvcp71d.dll is for dynamic linking - debug - CRT library for .Net 2003?

Now the project is to be used in VS.net 2003 OR VC6, that's what's written in the readme file.
So i opened the project in VC6 (which i'm more used to, concerning C++) and I don't understand why it's requiring (when debugging) the dll of 71d, shouldn't be asking for msvcpd.dll or msvcp60d.dll?

I think that the project is being linked to a wrong CRT library, probably due to being converted to VC.net 2003 . So i'm wondering if there's a way to link the project back to the older CRT library of VC6?

Comment: It's probably stored in the project settings. You converted the project, didn't start a new one, so of course it'll link to the same dlls. MSVCP71.dll for release, MSVCP71D.dll for debug, that's all. Also if it ends in 71 it's probably VS 7.1 project.

Comment: I know i said that, but the project is originally a VC6 project. There's the dsp (for project)file and the dsw (for workspace). So it must have been converted. 
I opened the same project in VC6 now, and i don't have VS 2003. And i want the project to link to the old CRT not the 71 one

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the linker the right lib you want to use.

.libs come always by couple:
- a big static one or 
- a small one that will require a dll at execution time, each small one is related to a specific dll. so you need to ask the linker: 
please use this mylib..v6...lib so I'll need the corresponding mylib..6...dll when executing.